# How do you prove that the mean of the co-primes of a number is half the number?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Say $n = 6$, The set of co-primes is $\{1, 5\}$, $\text{mean} = 3$

For $n = 9$, the set of co-primes is $\{1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8 \}, \text{mean} = 4.5$

> **Question**: Prove that the *mean* of co-primes of $n$, which are less than $n$ is half the number itself.

I computed all values until $10000$ and it seems to hold good.

Comment: HINT : $(a,n)=(n-a,n)$

Comment: Do you mean that if a & n are co-prime, so are n-a & n?

Comment: so you will always have pairs of co-primes that add to the number

Comment: yes. the GCD are same as $d$ divides $a$ and $n\implies d|(n-a)$ and vice versa.

Comment: i got to the point where i noticed that it was always an even number of co-primes!

Comment: if $a=n-a, n=2a, (n,a)=(2a,a)=a$. The number of co-primes is even if $a>1$

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8846/discussion-between-sureshvv-and-lab-bhattacharjee)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm posting a separate answer because I think Inceptio's is far too complicated for a problem this simple.

Note that $a$ is relatively prime to $n$ if and only if $n - a$ is relatively prime to $n$.  Also, generally $a \ne n - a$ (though there is one exception, which you have to deal with separately.  Can you find the exception?)
Anyway, this means we can make a list of everything relatively prime to $n$ in pairs of the form $(a, n - a)$, i.e. our list is:
$$
a_1, n - a_1, a_2, n - a_2, a_3, n - a_3, \cdots , a_k, n - a_k
$$

We can also guarantee that this list is all-inclusive (why?) and that no number appears twice (how?).
Then simply add up the numbers in the list and divide by the total.  You should get that the average is $\frac{n}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{a_1, \dots a_{ \phi(n)} \}$ be set of all co-primes of $n$, you notice that $a_{\phi(n)}=n-1( Why?)$ and $a_1=1$.

Let $n= p_1^{\alpha_1} \cdots p_k^{\alpha_j}$ ,  $p_i \nmid a_k$ where $1 \le i \le k$ and $1 \le j \le \phi(n)$

As rightly noted by Battacharjee in his [comment,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397343/how-do-you-prove-that-the-mean-of-the-co-primes-of-a-number-is-half-the-number#comment850436_397343) $\gcd({n,a_i})=1=\gcd(a_i,n-a_i)$

And the proof for that:

$(n,a_i)=d \implies n=df, a=dt \implies \gcd(dt,d(f-t))=d=\gcd(a_i,n)$,since $\gcd(t,f)=1$.

Here $\gcd(a_i, n)=1 \implies \gcd(a_i,n-a_i)=1$

Note that: $a_i, n-a_i \in \{a_1, \dots a_{ \phi(n)} \}$

$$\sum_1^{\phi(n)}a_i= \dfrac{\phi(n) n}{2}$$

Now the result is quite direct.

$$\text{Mean}= \dfrac{\sum_1^{\phi(n)}a_i}{\phi(n)}=\dfrac{n}{2}$$

**Some things that need to be explained:**

$\phi(n)$ denotes the [Totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). Number of co-primes of $n$ , less than $n$. You should read more about it.

$a_i, n-a_i \in \{a_1, \dots a_{ \phi(n)} \}$(Why?)

Because: $\gcd(a_i, n-a_i)=1$, and all numbers which are co prime to $n$ are in the set, which means they are in the set.

The answer looks too complicated only because of notations. Look at Goos' answer.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Considered it, sir.

Comment: I wasn't knighted (so far).

Comment: I think the $\phi$ function should not be introduced for a question this simple, because it does nothing to help the proof.  You also give a prime factorization for $n$, but then you don't use it at all :P

Comment: @Goos: I thought of using the factorization in finding $\phi(n)$, then I thought it was a bad idea. And still the factorization serves little purpose.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: You are knighted Marshal though.;)

Answer (score 0):

I assume $n\neq2$. The case $n=2$ should be treated separately (see Goos' comment).

Since $\gcd(a,n)=1\iff\gcd(n-a,n)=1$ it follows that if $C=\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_r\}$ is the set of the co-prime positive integers with $n$ (and smaller of $n$) then we can write $$C=\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_s,n\color{brown}{-a_s},\ldots,n\color{brown}{-a_2},n\color{brown}{-a_1}\}$$
for $s=\dfrac{r}{2}$.

 
In your examples for $n=6$, $C=\{1,5\}=\{1,6\color{brown}{-1}\}$ and

 
for $n=9$, $C=\{1,2,4,5,7,8\}=\{1,2,4,9\color{brown}{-4},9\color{brown}{-2},9\color{brown}{-1}\}$.

Therefore $\sum C=s\cdot n$ and the mean is $\dfrac{\sum C}{2s}=\dfrac{s\cdot n}{2s}=\dfrac{n}{2}$.

Comment: You forgot to deal with the case $a = n - a$.  Trivial, but still should be dealt with.