# Summation and product over $k$ with $k$ prime to $n$ sought

Tags: elementary-number-theory, trigonometry, algebraic-number-theory

I just come to a standstill with the following two formulas.

If 
$$E_n=\lbrace k\mid 1\le k\le n\ \&\ (k,n)=1\rbrace$$
then I hope for a closed formula $f(n)$ for those

1. $$\sum_{E_n}k$$
2. $$\prod_{E_n}\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)$$

Would be welcome if the Euler totient $\phi$ function would appear in $f(n)$.

Comment: For $(2),$ see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclotomicPolynomial.html

Comment: The first should be available here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569210/sum-of-all-coprimes-of-a-number

Comment: The cyclotomic polynomials deal with $e^{\frac{2\pi ik}{n}}$ but I am looking for $\cos(\frac{k\pi}{n})$ without the factor of $2$.

Answer (score 0):

For (2) I made a calculation for $n\ge 3$ and get

$$\prod_{E_n}\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)=\frac{\Phi_n(-1)}{2^{\phi(n)}}$$

This formula may be totally wrong at this moment.

I have not the CAS Mathematica available and also not the programming skills to check it by other CAS freely available.

Comment: Maybe I missed a factor of $(-1)^{\frac{\phi(n)}{2}}$ on the right side as the formula is not correct and I dont find the error in my calculation. To calculate $\phi(n)$ by logarithm it would be sufficient to take the absolute value on the left side.